# Redirect back with flash message for the layout template

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, flash-message

In my controller I have a function to login a user.

In case the login was successful I can simply use `return Redirect::back()`.

My problem starts when the credentials are incorrect and I want to redirect with a flash message.

I know I can chain the `with` method to the Redirect, but that would send the data to the specific view, and NOT to the layout, where the login HTML lies.

I could load a view like so:

```
$this->layout
     ->with('flash',$message)
     ->content = View::make('index');
```

But I need to redirect back to the referring page.

Is it possible to redirect while passing data to the layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Laravel Validator class handles this quite well....
The way I usually do it is to add a conditional within my layout/view in blade...

```
{{ $errors->has('email') ? 'Invalid Email Address' : 'Condition is false. Can be left blank' }}
```

This will display a message if anything returns with an error..
Then in your validation process you have...

```
 $rules = array(check credentials and login here...);

$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validation->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to('login')->with_errors($validation);
}
```

This way...when you go to the login page, it will check for errors regardless of submission, and if it finds any, it displays your messages.

**EDITED SECTION**
For dealing with the Auth class..
This goes in your view...

```
@if (Session::has('login_errors'))
    <span class="error">Username or password incorrect.</span>
@endif
```

Then in your auth...something along these lines..

```
 $userdata = array(
    'username'      => Input::get('username'),
    'password'      => Input::get('password')
);
if ( Auth::attempt($userdata) )
{
    // we are now logged in, go to home
    return Redirect::to('home');
}
else
{
    // auth failure! lets go back to the login
    return Redirect::to('login')
        ->with('login_errors', true);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. While possible, logging a user is usually done with the Auth class

Comment: Yeah, you would use Session::has('login_errors') in this case

Comment: Hi @KyleK, can you explain more about with('login_errors', true), why need to be login_erros, and what is the 2nd parameter doing? Thanks!

Comment: @Shiro, 'login_errors' is just an arbitrary name.... It really could be anything you want.  And the 'true' parameter is just setting the value of 'login_errors' to true....cuz when login fails, we want this value to be true....so that in the view, that if statement in the view then checks if 'login_errors' is true, and displays a message.  Basically..the ->with() method is just a key/value data pair....so first parameter is the key, second is the value. (in this case just a boolean)......most of the time you usually use ->with() to pass data to the view.

Comment: haha.. thanks for the explaination. Now I got the big picture. First I thought login_errors is some kind of preset function key word or what. I can't get much documentation about this yet. Thank you so much Kylek!